# Range of balls needed in lottery for 0 and 1 match to be equally likely with 5 balls drawn

Tags: probability

The question is if there is a lottery in which 5 balls are drawn randomly without replacement, what is the number range of the balls needed so that matching exactly 0 of those balls or matching exactly 1 of them is equally likely (or as close to equally likely as possible)? Assume all balls are numbered sequentially from 1 to n (such as 1,2,3...n).  Solve for n.

I know this can be solved by trial and error but is there a mathematical way to get the answer without first guessing and then making corrections/adjustments?

I was also able to solve it using wolframalpha but how can someone solve it mathematically, either getting an exact same probability for matching exactly 0 or 1 ball(s) or such that the probability of matching exactly 0 or 1 is the closest it can be?

The idea is a hypothetical lottery wants to make it easier to match at least 1 ball so maybe more people play or people that play continue to do so.  So the lottery designer is interested to first find out where 0 and 1 matches are about equal, then adjust it slightly to favor at least 1 match.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered writing down some formulae in terms of $n$ balls to match $x$ balls?

Comment: Yes I had wolframalpha solve (n choose 5) = 5 * (n choose 4) for n > 10 but when I tried to use pencil and paper to solve it, I ran into some problems.  In this example I got lucky and they match but suppose they didn't match but just got close, then I am not sure how to solve it even using wolframalpha without doing some trial and error.  I am looking for a mathematical solution to get the answer correct without having to plug and try many times.  That is, a general solution that would work even if I used 6 balls instead of 5 for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I think you're asking, generalized slightly. There are $n$ balls numbered $1, \ldots, n$. Lottery players choose $k$ distinct numbers with $k < n$, then $k$ balls are drawn. Tickets are rewarded according to the number of matches.

Each ticket should have the same probability distribution, so wlog assume that the player chooses $1, \ldots, k$. Then:

- The number of zero-match drawings is $\binom{n-k}{k}$, the number of $k$-element subsets of $\{k+1, \ldots, n\}$. Note that at least one match is guaranteed unless $2k \leq n$.
- The number of one-match drawings is $k \binom{n-k}{k-1}$, the number of one-element subsets of $\{1, \ldots, k\}$ times the number of $k-1$-element subsets of $\{k+1, \ldots, n\}$.

Solving for $n$:
\begin{align*}
\binom{n-k}{k} &= k \binom{n-k}{k-1} \\
\frac{(n-k)!}{k! (n-2k)!} &= \frac{k (n-k)!}{(k-1)! (n-2k+1)!} \\
\frac{(k-1)!}{k(k!)} &= \frac{(n-2k)!}{(n-2k+1)!} \\
\frac{1}{k^2} &= \frac{1}{n - 2k + 1} \\
n &= k^2 + 2k - 1
\end{align*}

So $n = 34$ for $k = 5$.

If you have the R programming language and the `tidyverse` package installed, then the following function will let you simulate the lottery. `balls` and `draws` are the total number of balls and the number of balls drawn ($n$ and $k$ in my notation above), and `trials` is the number of simulations to run. The output is a data frame with two columns: `num_matches` lists integers from 0 to `draws`, and `num_trials` shows the number of trials that gave that number of matches with a ticket marked 1, ..., `draws`.

```
lottery <- function(balls, draws, trials) { 
  tibble(trial=rep(1:trials, each=draws),
         result=as.vector(replicate(trials,
                          sample(1:balls, draws)))) %>% 
  group_by(trial) %>%
  mutate(match=(result<=draws)) %>% 
  summarize(num_matches=sum(match)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(num_matches) %>%
  summarize(num_trials=n())
```

}

I tried running this with 200,000 trials and got good results:

```
> lottery(34, 5, 2e5)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  num_matches num_trials
        <int>      <int>
1           0      85350
2           1      85338
3           2      26260
4           3       2941
5           4        111

  > lottery(62, 7, 2e5)
  # A tibble: 6 x 2
    num_matches num_trials
          <int>      <int>
  1           0      82073
  2           1      82850
  3           2      29922
  4           3       4777
  5           4        364
  6           5         14
```

I'll note that as $k$ increases, the outcomes of this lottery seem to reproduce the Poisson distribution for $\lambda = 1$, and the probabilities of $0$ and $1$ matches approach $1/e$. I can't think of a quick explanation for this immediately. The probability of zero matches in this lottery is \begin{align*}\frac{ \binom{k^2 + k - 1}{k}}{\binom{k^2 + 2k - 1}{k}} &= \frac{ \frac{(k^2 + k - 1)!}{k! (k^2-1)!}} {\frac{(k^2 + 2k-1)!}{k! (k^2 + k + 1)!}} \\
&= \frac{(k^2 + k + 1)!^2}{(k^2 + 2k - 1)!(k^2 - 1)! } \\
&= \frac{k^2 (k^2 + 1) (k^2 + 2) \cdots (k^2 + k - 1)}{(k^2 + 2k) (k^2 + 2k + 1) \cdots (k^2 + 2k - 1)} \\
&= \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{k^2+i}{k^2 + 2k + i} \\
&= \exp \left( -\sum_{i=1}^{k} \log \left( 1 - \frac{2k}{k^2 + 2k + i} \right) \right)\end{align*}
and perhaps that last sum could be shown to go to $1$ by a clever use of asymptotics.

Comment: Wow so no matter how many balls are drawn, there is an integer solution to the highest numbered ball needed?  That is a little surprising to me.  For example, if 9 "winning" balls were drawn, then the chances of matching either exactly 0 or exactly 1 of those winning numbers would be equal if there were balls numbered 1 thru 98 inclusive?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think I have a solution to this specific problem.

to match exactly 0 balls: ${5 \choose 0}$ * ${n \choose 5}$

to match exactly 1 ball : ${5 \choose 1}$ * ${n \choose 4}$

Here n is the number of "losing" balls so the final answer will be 5+n as the highest numbered ball.

So we know ${n \choose 5}$ is n (n-1) (n-2) (n-3) (n-4) / 120

and we know $5 * {n \choose 4}$ is 5 * n (n-1) (n-2) (n-3) ( ) / 24 (empty parens to show "missing" term)

multiply the 2nd equation by 5/5 to get 25 * n (n-1) (n-2) (n-3) ( ) / 120

now we can drop the /120 since both equations have it and then we multiply both equations by (n-4) (since it is missing from the bottom one)

Now the equations are exactly the same except the top one has an extra (n-4) and the bottom one has a 25 so if we are solving for both equations being equal, that means that 25 = (n-4) so n = 29 which means there have to be 29 losing balls for the lottery to have even chances for exactly 0 or 1 matches, so if the highest numbered ball is 34, I think it is a solution.

However, if the probability of exactly 0 or 1 matching balls is not exactly equal, this method might not work.